# How to format and access data in 2D vector arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to use vectors to create 2D arrays in c++ and for some reason I get this error when doing so,

`expression must have pointer to object type`

the error is apparently on this line:

`std::cout << "item" << i << ": " << toSim[i][j] << std::endl;`

when I look up anything about 2D vectors I always see people using the syntax I'm using to access data from them but its giving me an error, I also get this error for the line defining the vector, am I defining its contents incorrectly?

`no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [with _Ty=float, _Alloc=std::allocator<float>]" matches the argument list`

also, here's the full code:

```
class movmentCalculator
{
private:

    std::vector<float> toSim { {5, 5, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 6, 6}, {7, 7, 7, 7} };

public:

    void printStack() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < toSim.size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < toSim.size(); j++)
            {
                std::cout << "item" << i << ": " << toSim[i][j] << std::endl;
            }

    }
};
```

Comment: `toSim` is a 1D vector

Comment: std::vector<vector<<float>> toSim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<float>` is a 1D vector. Hence your errors.

To be accepted by the compiler, your code can be corrected as follows:

```
class movmentCalculator
{
private:

    std::vector<std::vector<float>> toSim { {5, 5, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 6, 6}, {7, 7, 7, 7} };

public:

    void printStack() 
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < toSim.size(); ++i)
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < toSim[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                std::cout << "item" << i << ": " << toSim[i][j] << std::endl;
            }

    }
};
```

But you could easily have solved it on your own (in my opinion).

Comment: thanks, when i looked through 2d vector arrays I noticed they used that but I assumed that was just a template for some other stuff they were also doing, and other sites had it with just the term vector in and nothing else and when I did that it complained I hadnt defined it so I assumed the same for them

Comment: @Evansnye_ Actually you can flatten a 2D vector in a 1D vector. This way, you should access the data through `toSim[(ncol * row) + col]`.